# Postgres regex to delimit multiple optional matches

Tags: regex, postgresql

Suppose a text field needs to be delimited in PostgreSQL.  It is formatted as `'abcd'` where each variable can be any one of: `1.4`, `3`, `5`, `10`, `15`, `20` or `N/A`.  Here is a query with some examples, followed by their expected results:

```
WITH example AS(
SELECT '10N/AN/AN/A' AS bw
UNION SELECT '1010N/AN/A'
UNION SELECT '101020N/A'
UNION SELECT '35N/A1.4'
UNION SELECT '1010N/A10'
UNION SELECT '105N/AN/A'
UNION SELECT '1.43N/A20'
)
SELECT
    bw
    ,regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(
                regexp_replace(
                    regexp_replace(
                        regexp_replace(
                            regexp_replace(bw, '(1\.4)', E'\\&|', 'g')
                        , '(3)', E'\\&|', 'g')
                    , '(5)', E'\\&|', 'g')
                , '(10)', E'\\&|', 'g')
            , '(15)', E'\\&|', 'g')
        , '(20)', E'\\&|', 'g')
    , '(N/A)', E'\\&|', 'g')

FROM
    example
```

Results:

```
bw:text,      regexp_replace:text
'1010N/AN/A', '10|10|N/A|N/A|'
'1010N/A10',  '10|10|N/A|10|'
'35N/A1.4',   '3|5|N/A|1.4|'
'1.43N/A20',  '1.4|3|N/A|20|'
'105N/AN/A',  '10|5|N/A|N/A|'
'101020N/A',  '10|10|20|N/A|'
'10N/AN/AN/A','10|N/A|N/A|N/A|'
```

I'm not worried about the trailing pipe '|' since I can deal with it.  This gets me what I want, but I'm concerned I could be doing it more succinctly.  I experimented with putting each of the capture groups in a single regexp_replace statement while scouring through the documentation, but I was unable to get these results.

Can this be achieved within a single regexp_replace statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may build a `(1\.4|3|5|1[50]|20|N/A)` [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with [**alternation operators**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) separating the alternatives and replace with `\1|`:

```
select regexp_replace('35N/A1.4', '(1\.4|3|5|1[50]|20|N/A)', '\1|','g'); 
-- 35|N/A|1.4|
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/MTL68482)

**Details**

- `(` - starting the capturing group construct
- `1\.4` - `1.4` substring (`.` must be escaped in order to be parsed as a literal dot, else, it matches any char)
- `|` - or
- `3` - a `3` char
- `|` - or
- `5` - a `5` char
- `|` - or
- `1[50]` - `1` followed with either `5` or `0` (the `[...]` is called a bracket expression where you may specify chars, char ranges or even character classes)
- `|` - or
- `20` - a `20` substring
- `|` - or
- `N/A`  - a `N/A` substring
- `)` - end of the capturing group.

The `\1` in the replacement pattern is a [**numbered replacement backreference**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) (also called a (group) placeholder) that references the value captured into Group 1.

Comment: I wish more regex answers came with this level of explanation.  Thanks!